# WHERE working as an IF?

Tags: sql-server

I'm not sure what is this code doing. I think it works as an If / CASE, or I am wrong?

```
UPDATE #Clasif3 SET
vari_codigo = 0,
vari_nombre = ''
WHERE @ConsVariedad = -9
```

Comment: If `@ConsVariedad` is anything other than -9, this does nothing. What is hard to understand?

Comment: Does googling for `SQL WHERE` suddenly not work anymore?

Comment: @TT This does NOT conditionally set only some rows. The update is based on the value of a variable. If that variable = -9 it updates the entire temp table. Otherwise it updates nothing.

Comment: @TT. `@ConsVariedad` is not a column, it's a variable.

Comment: Oh right, silly me :)

Comment: Have you tried looking into how to use [Where Clauses](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)? Im honestly not very good at sql but i am sapposed to be starting it soon , What exactly are you trying to do? all i really notice is a string variable and an int variable

Comment: I don't understand why people are voting to close this question for not being clear. The question is extremely clear. The OP posted code and doesn't understand what it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `WHERE` clause is evaluated once per row<sup>1</sup>. If it happens to make no reference to any columns within a row and is entirely based on deterministic functions, then that means that it will produce the same result when evaluated for each row<sup>2</sup>, which means that either no rows pass the `WHERE` clause or they all do.

Thus, you may (logically) consider it as being similar to guarding the entire query with an `IF`, with the difference being that this query will always produce a result set (either empty or full) whereas a query that is only conditionally executed will not produce a result set at all if not evaluated.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Here, where only one table is involved, this is straightforwardly "once per row in the table". Where a `FROM` clause is involved and there are multiple tables, this in "once per row in the result set produced by the `FROM` clause", which may means that it is evaluated multiple times for some rows from the original source tables, depending on the `JOIN` conditions.

<sup>2</sup>In practice, as Martin points out, the optimizer should be able to determine this fact also and only evaluate the predicate once.

<sup>3</sup>Where I talk about result sets, I was mostly thinking about `SELECT` queries. The logic is the same for an `UPDATE`, but of course we don't expect it to produce a result set at all, merely an indication of the number of rows affected, and to fire triggers, if any are defined.

Comment: Logically it is evaluated per row. In reality the plan will likely have a filter with a start up predicate meaning that if the condition is not met no rows at all are ever requested.

Comment: @MartinSmith - agreed.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE #Clasif3 SET
vari_codigo = 0,
vari_nombre = ''
WHERE @ConsVariedad = -9
```

`#` infront table name represents local temporary tables which are private to the process that created them. Here `Clasif3` is the temp table.

```
vari_codigo = 0,
vari_nombre = ''
```

are the columns in that table. U are updating the value of these fields

```
WHERE @ConsVariedad = -9
```

means the code updates the rows where `ConsVariedad  = -9`

`@` is used to represent a variable in sql coding

Hope this helps :)